# Criar arquivos JSON relacionando arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tenho dois arquivos json, um com id, estado e sigla e o outro com a id do estado e as cidades desse estado. Eu fiz a leitura desses arquivos e gravei o conteúdo em arrays, mas eu preciso criar um arquivo para cada estado com suas respectivas cidades, relacionando os ids. Até agora consegui criar os arquivos separados por estado no primeiro FOR, mas estou em dúvida de como colocar as cidades de cada um em seu conteúdo, só consegui mesmo criar os arquivos e a estrutura inicial do JSON:

Exemplo de arquivo que terá que ser criado:

ES.json

```
[{
    "ID": "1",
    "Nome": "Afonso Cláudio",
},
     {
    "ID": "2",
    "Nome": "Água Doce do Norte",
},
     {
    "ID": "3",
    "Nome": "Águia Branca",
},
]
```

Todas essas cidades fazem parte do ES, então preciso de um arquivo para cada estado e suas respectivas cidades.

[Link para os arquivos Json](https://github.com/felipefdl/cidades-estados-brasil-json)

```
var fs = require("fs");

let dataStates = fs.readFileSync("Estados.json", "utf8");

let states = JSON.parse(dataStates);
let sigla = states.map((state) => {
  const { ID, Sigla, Nome } = state;
  return {
    idstate: ID,
    sigla: Sigla,
    estadoNome: Nome,
  };
});
//console.log(sigla);

let dataCities = fs.readFileSync("Cidades.json", "utf8");

let cities = JSON.parse(dataCities);
let nome = cities.map((city) => {
  const { ID, Nome, Estado } = city;
  return {
    idcity: ID,
    cidadeNome: Nome,
    cidadeEstado: Estado,
  };
});
//console.log(nome);

const initialJson = {
  nextId: 1,
  cidades: [],
};

for(i = 0; i < sigla.length; i++){
  fs.writeFileSync(sigla[i].sigla + '.json', JSON.stringify(initialJson));

    for(l = 0; l < nome.length; l++){
      cidades = { id: nextId++, name: nome[l].cidadeNome };
      cidades.push(cidades);
      fs.writeFileSync(sigla[i].sigla + '.json', JSON.stringify(cidades));
}
}
```

Comment: Faltou um exemplo dos dois arquivos. Do jeito que está temos que interpretar o seu código para tentar realizar uma engenharia reversa e descobrir o que tem neles. Parece trabalhoso demais, não?

Comment: Colquei umas imagens para facilitar o entendimento

Comment: Não dá pra copiar e colar de um `json` em uma imagem. Saiba mais sobre isso em: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas - Postar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/59479).

Comment: Coloquei o link para os arquivos

Comment: Dê um exemplo também de um dos arquivos de estado que devem ser gerados. Não precisa ter todas as cidades, só um exemplo com umas duas cidades já está de bom tamanho.

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do resultado de saída?

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo lá, basicamente preciso criar um arquivo para cada estado, com a sigla como nome e as suas respectivas cidades como conteúdo, não sei se o exemplo ficou bom mas qualquer coisa melhoro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Separe as cidades por grupos usando a função [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) resultando na criação um [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) que agrupa as cidades por estado;
- Percorra o `array` de estados obtendo todas as cidades de cada um do [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) criado anteriormente por meio da função [`Map.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get);
- Salve o valor obtido no último item com a função [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options).

---

```
const fs = require('fs');

const cidades = require('./Cidades.json');
const estados = require('./Estados.json');

const mapear = (resultado, { Estado: estado, ...cidade }) => {
  const acumulador = resultado.get(estado) || [];

  return resultado.set(estado, [...acumulador, cidade]);
};

const salvar = (mapa, { ID: id, Sigla: sigla }) => {
  fs.writeFileSync(`${sigla}.json`, JSON.stringify(mapa.get(id), null, 2));
};

const mapa = cidades.reduce(mapear, new Map());
estados.forEach((estado) => salvar(mapa, estado));
```

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

---

> [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
>
> O objeto `Map` é um mapa simples de chave/valor.

---

> [`Map.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)
>
> O método `get()` retorna um elemento específico de um objeto de `Map`.